# How to type hint self.client.patch in django.test.TestCase?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, python-unittest, python-typing

I am wondering what type hint to use as the output of `_request` in the following Django test case:

```py
from django.test import TestCase

class SomeTestCase(TestCase):

    def _request(self, id: int, update_data: dict[str, Any]) -> ?:
        url = reverse('path', kwargs={'id': id})
        return self.client.patch(url, update_data)

    ...
```

Comment: https://github.com/typeddjango/django-stubs/blob/c1cb879d1651c52ed2f1e6424af73aa7096aa1e3/django-stubs/test/client.pyi#L210. Ignore it's private - its name starts with underscore just because such class does not exist at runtime and is purely for stubs (and because I did not expect anyone to use this type somewhere else when writing that stub part). Guard your import with `if TYPE_CHECKING` and this should be enough.